# Java - set environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have a piece of code that looks something like this:

```
if(System.getenv(ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS_SYS) == null){
    //here I want to do something like:
    //System.setenv(ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS_SYS,"");
}
```

Any idea how to set the `environment variable` like in the comment?

I do not want to launch a new process or anything like that, I want to set it for the current process.

Thanks.
Regards,

Serban

Answer (score -3):

You can use System.getProperty and System.setProperty

Comment: Those methods may require elevation imho, thats why they may throw `SecurityException`.

Comment: Env variable is not the same as System property